# Code workbook, SQL - why is this code not running and producing an error of 'invalid number of arguments' for ISNULL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, palantir-foundry

I'm reporting a potential bug with the ISNULL statement for SQL in code workbook, or if not wondering why my code does not run (image of the select statement of code)?
The code runs fine when the column is not wrapped in the ISNULL statement, and the error log quotes that it expects just one argument for ISNULL (though my understanding is that there are two arguments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 ).

I can supply more info on request.

Select statement from the code that I'm attempting to run
[image: Select statement from the code that I'm attempting to run]

Message from the error log
[image: Message from the error log]

Comment: would it be possible for you to replace the screenshots with code instead. please? you can also copy paste the stacktrace. It's more SEO friendly

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the same functionality in Spark SQL you can try

```
select if(isnull(OUT2021.financial_year),'',OUT2021.financial_year) as financial_Year from table
```

> OR

```
spark.sql("""
  select
    case when OUT2021.financial_year is null then '' else OUT2021.financial_year end as financial_Year
  from
    TableName 
""")
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution in Spark SQL!

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug, Spark sql `isnull` only takes one argument https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#isnull

```
> SELECT isnull(1);
 false
```

The link you listed is from Microsoft's SQL (Transact-SQL) which is a different syntax.